# Add Red Dot on image using CSS?

Tags: css, image, overlay

I'm wondering if it would be possible to create a CSS style that can enable a small red dot to show up overlaying an image to indicate that it was sold?

Can you overlay a transparent image on another image using CSS?

Answer (score 6):

This code generates a red dot over the container `div`:

```css
#cont {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #aaa; /*To show the boundaries of the element*/
    }
    #cont:before {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        background-color:#FF0000;
        border-radius:50%;
        opacity:0.5;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```

```html
<div id="cont">
<img src="" alt="image here" width="200" height="200">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create another element (div) for the status of the item. If the item is sold set a class on the item to sold. Then use border-radius on the status div in CSS to create the red dot.

Example:

```
.sold .status{
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #f00;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just put them one after the other and do something like `style="margin-top:-100px"` on the second one to move it on top of the previous one.

Comment: thanks AwokeKnowing - I don't want to have to make another image, just want to overlay this red dot when something has sold.

Answer (score 0):

Basically,

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul::marker 
{
list-style-type: circle;
position:absolute;
}
li{
color: red;
}
```